# Using binomial distribution, how can I find tthe probability of getting <= 3 fives in 20 rolls of a dice?

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-theorem, binomial-distribution

Using the formula for binomial distribution (which I believe to be: nCx ∙ P^x  ∙ (1 – P)^(n - x)), how could I determine the probability of rolling less than or equal to 3 fives in 20 rolls of the dice?

I understand the nature of solving a binomial story problem and have come to the following:

- Success = Rolling a 5
- Probability of success (P) (Is this not what I
  need to calculate??): p = 1.6
- Probability of failure: q = 5/6
- Number of trials: n = 20
- Number of successes out of those trials: x = 0, x =
  1, x = 2, x = 3

I'm really stumped and don't understand where to go from here, any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have the values and you have the formula. Simply plug in the values and add them

Comment: What's consfusing me is what value to use for x

Comment: $P(X \le 3)=P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)+P(X=3)= C(20,0)p^0(1-p)^{20} + C(20,1)p^1(1-p)^{19}+C(20,2)p^2(1-p)^{18}+C(20,3)p^3(1-p)^{17}$

Comment: ah okay, I understand how to sub in the values now! In order to determine the probability is it just a matter of using this formula? I'm not sure what I actually need to calculate...

Comment: You need to calculate the probability of rolling less than or equal to 3 fives in 20 rolls of the dice.

Comment: I understand that is what I need to determine, maybe a better phrasing would be I don't know how to calculate this

Comment: There are 4 ways to get a total of 5 when rolling two dice. $P(5) = 4/36 = 1/11.$ Let $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=20, p=1/11).$ Then you need $P(X \le 3) = 0.8245837.$ You can get this in R using `pbinom(3, 20, 1/11)` or by plugging in $p=1/11$ into equations in previous useful comments. (I wouldn't advise a normal approximation.)

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone!